# How to draw circles with a radius based on lat/long data in DB

Tags: geometry, openlayers-2, buffer, sqlite

I have a . sqlite file with many columns, two of those columns being `lat` and `long`.

I've been searching around for a bit now (don't think I want to be using `BuildCircleMbr` from spatialite?) but I'm not entirely too sure how to go about it.

I'm thinking it has something to do with `GeomFromText` but can't get the query set up correctly.

Final product would be having these circles and display them on a map using MapServer/OpenLayers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need the BuildCircleMbr. Define a SpatiaLite layer in mapfile, giving the DATA string like:

```
DATA "SELECT BuildCircleMbr(lat, long, radius) FROM your_table"
```

Create an `OpenLayers.Layers.Mapserver` layer (or WMS layer if you serve the mapfile in WMS) in OpenLayers js script.

Comment: Hi @Mingfeng, thank you for the reply. When I add that in the mapfile (and of course in OL js) I'm not getting any data on the screen (no errors in mapserver log either). More importantly, if I just run that SELECT statement I'm getting `no such function: BuildCircleMbr`. Does this have to do with m version of sqlite? `version -v` returns 3.7.5

Comment: Never used spatialite before, so I'm not sure. But did you install spatialite extension for your sqlite?

Comment: Sorry, that was a poor question. We had spatialite on our server, but I had to install spatialite-tools. If I do the query `SELECT BuildCircleMbr(lat, long, radius) FROM your_table` I don't get an error but it doesn't return anything (no mapserver log error, just no POI data showing up). Also, when I access the .sqlite file from cmd line, I'm not doing `sqlite3 POIs.sqlite`, I'm doing `spatialite POIs.sqlite`. Is this ok? If I try to do a .load once inside sqlite3, I get an error: file or directory not found.

Comment: If you have some tool that can execute sql statement, it's better to do the query there first instead of in mapfile, just to check if the query returns the right data.

Comment: Right right that's what I was trying to say: I just do the query within sqlite3, I don't get an error but it doesn't return anything (not like it's going to draw a circle on the screen within sqlite3 :) ). That being said, it SHOULD be returning something right?

Comment: yes, it should. Does the query "SELECT lat, long FROM your_table", without the BuildCircleMbr function, return anything?

Comment: Yep sure does, lat and long returned separated by a pipe. As for your initial answer up top: I should be able to just supply an integer for radius, right? I don't need to have that in the DB?

Comment: yes, you can just provide an integer for radius.

Comment: Right, I agree. Wonder what the issue is...

Comment: What radius are you inputting? 1 degree is about 69 miles at 37 degrees north. If your geometry is Geographic - lat/long then your units are probably decimal degrees. For a 1 mile Circle you might want .014